# How does XGBoost implement MAE loss?

Tags: xgboost, loss-function

As we all know, XGBoost constructs trees based on gradient.
I wonder how does XGBoost define gradient of MAE loss, as MAE itself is not differentiable.

After some digging of the source code, I found the implementation of MSE loss [here](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/7c6673cb9ef7f68f92075123dc78e9661ce3d4e5/src/objective/regression_obj.cc#L23). But I can't find any implementation of MAE loss. The original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754) didn't discuss MAE loss either.

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost does **not** implement MAE as a loss function.

XGBoost does implement MAE as a [evaluation metric](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html).